# testing out of disk space in linux

Tags: linux, testing

I have a program that may be dying when it runs out of disk space writing a certain file, I am not sure if this is the case.

I'd like to run it and see, but my test server is not going to run out of space any time soon. Is there any way I could mock this behavior? It doesn't look like there is any way to set a folder/file size limit in Ubuntu, and getting user quotas set up is going to be a process ( due to getting permissions )

Is there a common way of testing this situation?

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Do you have spare USB memory sticks handy? Would be easy to fill up one of those.

Comment: Why not just setup a partition that is really small?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

1. Create a file of the size you want (here 10MB)

   `dd if=/dev/zero of=/home/qdii/test bs=1024 count=10000`
2. Make a loopback device out of this file

   `losetup -f /home/qdii/test`
3. Format that device in the file system you want

   `mkfs.ext4 /dev/loopXXX`
4. Mount it wherever you want (`/mnt/test` should exist)

   `sudo mount /dev/loopXXX /mnt/test`
5. Copy your program on that partition and test

   `cp /path/my/program /mnt/test && cd /mnt/test && ./program`

---

Substitute `/dev/loopXXX` with the loop device `losetup` created, find out with `losetup -a` .

When done, don't forget to:

- unmount with `sudo umount /mnt/test` .
- clean up loop devices after use, with `losetup -D /dev/loopXXX`
- remove the file.

Comment: With `-D` option `losetup` will try to detach all loop devices, which are widely used (at least on Ubuntu), so I'd prefer `sudo losetup -d /dev/loopXX` to detach selected device.

Comment: Something that should be said: the `losetup` at least must be done as root. Otherwise one gets an error "losetup: cannot find an unused loop device".

Comment: @vinc17 in my case the error was 'failed to set up loop device: No such file or directory'. I also had to use `sudo` for the third step.

Answer (score 14):

Just use /dev/full, it will raise the ENOSPC error when you try to write to it:

```
$ echo "Hello world" > /dev/full
bash: echo: write error: No space left on device
```

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility would be to reduce the appropriate limit with [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) syscall with `RLIMIT_FSIZE` or with the `bash` [ulimit](http://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html) builtin (using `-f`). Then [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) would fail with `EFBIG`

And you could also set some [quotas](http://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.htmlsouptonuts.sourceforge.net/quota_tutorial.html) on some appropriate file system, so `write(2)` fails with `EDQOT`.

If you want the real `ENOSPC` error to `write(2)` you probably need a loopback file system as answered by [qdii](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16044420/841108).

BTW, I don't really know how to "emulate" the `EIO` error (maybe with some [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) filesystem?).

Many programs handle `write(2)` errors (and nearly all should). But I don't know many programs which handle very differently the various errors possible with `write(2)`. Most programs handle all `write(2)` errors the same way.

<sup>However, you might need to handle `EINTR` and `EWOULDBLOCK` errors differently: these are recoverable errors, and you usually redo the `write(2)` at some later time.</sup>

Comment: No, not better but different. And your solution gives the real `ENOSPC` error ....

Answer (score 0):

If you're making POSIX filesystem calls you can use [libfiu](https://blitiri.com.ar/p/libfiu/) to inject `ENOSPC` errors into calls.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to recreate the scenario is to mount a directory with limited space. Let's say that your program will be executed on /data. To limit the storage there to 100MB (customize as needed):

1. sudo su
2. mkdir /media/images/
3. dd if=/dev/zero of=/media/images/data.img bs=512K count=200 #100MB
4. mkfs.ext4 /media/images/data.img
5. mkdir /data
6. mount -o loop /media/images/data.img /data

But knock your socks off if you want even less space

- dd if=/dev/zero of=/media/images/data.img bs=1M count=1 #1MB