# Mocking disk-out-of-space in python unittests

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock, pyfakefs

I'm trying to write a unittest to test the behaviour of a function when the disk is full. I need file access functions to behave normally while most of the test runs, so that the file I'm creating is actually created, then at one point I need the disk to be 'full'. I can't find a way to do this using `mock_open()`, since the file object created by this doesn't seem to be persist between function calls. I've tried to use `pyfakefs` and setting the disk size using `self.fs.set_disk_usage(MAX_FS_SIZE)` but when I try to run this in my tests, it allows `used_size` to go negative, meaning there is always free space (though oddly, their example code works correctly).

Is there a way to either simulate a disk-out-space error at a particular point in my code? Mocking the write function to have a side-effect would be my immediate thought, but I can't access the file object that I'm writing to in my test code, as it's buried deep inside function calls.

Edit: looks like I've found a bug in pyfakefs

Edit2: bug in pyfakefs has been fixed; now works as expected. Still interested to know if there's a way to get f.write() to throw an OSError with a simple mock.

Comment: Maybe add the tests you've got + the example code?

Comment: Maybe you can use this question to get ideas https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16044204/testing-out-of-disk-space-in-linux

Comment: @GonzaloOdiard thanks; I had something like this set up initially, but it doesn't play well with our continuous integration server, so I'm looking for something at the python level, not the OS level.

Comment: @askvictor Check 0x263A's comment.